# Show/Hide more than one <table> with a checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, html-table, hide, show

I want to show and hide several tables on one page with one button. Unfortunately my script can only show and hide one table at a time.

I have a page with a lot of queries. There are also text fields in a table. For a better overview, the tables with the text fields should only be displayed when the checkbox is ticked. The checkbox should not be clicked at the beginning.

```js
function Displayer(n)
{
  var check = document.getElementById('Section'+n);
  if (check.style.display == 'none')
    {
      check.style.display='inline';
    }
    else
    {
      check.style.display='none';
    }
}
```

```html
<p><input type="checkbox" class="btnstylega" onClick="Displayer(99)" />Show Tables</p>

<table id="Section99" style="display:none;"> <td>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
</td></table>

<table id="Section99" style="display:none;"> <td>
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
</td></table><br>
```

I want to show and hide many tables without adjusting the tables by clicking on the checkbox.

Comment: You can't repeat the same Id, use class or name to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Improvement: It will add the event handler and trigger the change on load where needed

Note the data-attribute on the checkbox

```js
var chg = new Event('change');
document.querySelectorAll(".btnstylega").forEach(function(but) {
  but.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var checked = this.checked,
      section = this.getAttribute("data-tables");
    document.querySelectorAll('.Section' + section).forEach(function(sect) {
      sect.classList.toggle("hide",!checked);
    });
  })
  but.dispatchEvent(chg);
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="checkbox" class="btnstylega" data-tables="88" checked />Show Tables 88 </p>
<p><input type="checkbox" class="btnstylega" data-tables="99" />Show Tables 99</p>

<table class="Section88">
<tr>
  <td>
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="Section88">
<tr>
  <td>
    BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
  </td>
  </tr>
</table><hr>
<table class="Section99">
<tr>
  <td>
    CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="Section99">
<tr>
  <td>
    DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

An ID **must** be unique in a document. The tool to mark multiple elements as part of a group is a class.

Replace your `id` attributes with `class` attributes.

Then replace `getElementById` with `getElementsByClassName` (or `querySelectorAll`).

These methods return lists of nodes and not single elements, so *loop over the result* like an array and access the `style` property on each one in turn.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) must be unique in a document, you can use [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) instead. You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to target all the elements having the [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class), then loop through them to set the style. You can toggle the [`class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/class) using [`classList.toggle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods) like the following way:

```js
function Displayer()
{
  var check = document.querySelectorAll('.Section99');
  check.forEach(function(table){
    table.classList.toggle('show');
  });
}
```

```css
.Section99{
  display: none;
}
.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p><input type="checkbox" class="btnstylega" onClick="Displayer()" />Show Tables</p>

<table class="Section99" class="hide"> <td>
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA
</td></table>

<table class="Section99" class="hide"> <td>
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
</td></table><br>
```

Comment: You are hidding it not "Showing"

Comment: This code is not very flexible - at least pass the section number as before

Comment: @mplungjan, there is no use of passing the the section number in this case:)

Comment: Because you changed to hardcode the section. See my answer to see what I mean

Comment: @mplungjan, I really love to keep it simple in achieving what OP wants:)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Now everything works as I wanted it to. :)